# Grouping based on two columns

Tags: sql

I have the below table structure, where for multiple room bookings can be done for multiple date with some priority,

```
MeetingDate RoomID Priority
----------- ------ --------
2014-06-05  2      2
2014-06-05  3      3
2014-06-06  3      3
```

I want to filter high priority roomid for each date, when I use both meetingdate and roomid, it is not working, logically it will not work, pls do let me know for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  t1.MeetingDate, t1.RoomID
FROM your_table t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MeetingDate, MAX(Priority) AS MaxPriority
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY MeetingDate
) t2 ON t1.MeetingDate = t2.MeetingDate AND t1.Priority = t2.MaxPriority
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the solution

Answer (score 0):

If your priority is 1=highest priority and 3=lowest, you might be looking for

```
select
      yt.meetingDate,
      yt.roomID,
      min( yt.priority ) as highestPriority,
      count(*) as TimesBooked
   from
      yourTable yt
   group by
      yt.meetingDate,
      yt.roomID
```

So this way, you only get one record for a given date and room with the highest priority.  If your priority is reversed where 1 is low priority and 3 is high, then just change the MIN() to MAX()

Additionally, if you wanted to know if there were any POSSIBLE conflicts (ie: double-booking a room for a given date), you can add a count too which I added above.  So, if any have a "TimesBooked" greater than 1, you probably have a conflict/double-booking.

Comment: Thanks, how to find rooms with same priority?